# How do I check busybox version (from busybox)?

Tags: busybox

I'm using busybox in a embedded system, and I would like to check its version. How do I check the busybox version from within busybox?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Invoke the busybox binary as `busybox`, and you get a line with the Busybox version, a few more lines of fluff, and the list of utilities included in the binary.

```
busybox | head -1
```

Most utilities show a usage message if you call them with `--help`, with the version number in the first line.

```
ls --help 2>&1 | head -1
```

Comment: what is `2>&1 `, is it in case there are errors, print stderr to stdout as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/818265/1705829)

Comment: @Timo Yes, `2>&1` redirects standard error to standard output, and standard output is going through the pipe, so `… --help 2>&1 | …` sends the output through the pipe whether it's on standard output (which is where the help from `--help` normally goes) or standard error (which some programs use, especially programs that don't recognize `--help` but print a help message when they see an option they don't recognize).

Answer (score 4):

You can check the version on any system running busybox by running any of the commands with the `--help` flag to see usage. The first line of the usage calls includes a note about the busybox version:

```
$ cat --help
BusyBox v1.18.4 (2011-03-13 15:36:03 CET) multi-call binary.

Usage: cat [FILE]...

Concatenate FILEs and print them to stdout
```

If you are not running busybox but have it installed on your system, you can check by instantiating one of the utilities like so:

```
$ busybox cat --help
```

(Edit: As [Gilles notes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15895/how-do-i-check-busybox-version-from-busybox/15899#15899) you can also call the busybox binary without a command and get the same header)

Lastly, there is also a note at the end of the man page that shows what version it's from:

```
$ man busybox | tail -n 1
version 1.18.4    2011-03-13     BUSYBOX(1)
```

Comment: I'm using busybox in a embedded system. If I type `cat --version` on it, it shows `cat: unrecognized option '--version'`.

Comment: I also tried with `ls --version` with the same result `ls: unrecognized option '--version'`

Comment: @Tom, actually @Gilles has the right answer here, it's in the header of anything you run, so running the `busybox` binary directly makes the most sense. Mine only works for the same reason and throws an error besides. I'll correct it.

Comment: @Tom: I fixed my answer, use `--help` instead of `--version` :)

Answer (score 3):

Since it hasn't been mentioned, `sh --help` also works.

```
# sh --help
BusyBox v1.27.1 (2020-06-11 08:53:57 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: sh [-/+OPTIONS] [-/+o OPT]... [-c 'SCRIPT' [ARG0 [ARGS]] / FILE [ARGS]]

Unix shell interpreter
# _
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it not report the version when you connect,

i.e.

```
telnet 10.10.10.1

BusyBox v0.61.pre (2008.06.11-10:37+0000) Built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

#
```

or run (for example)

```
# busybox ash

BusyBox v1.17.1 (Debian 1:1.17.1-8) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

#
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check the busybox version is to look at the raw program file and only display lines that have BusyBox in them

```
strings $(which busybox) | grep \\\<BusyBox

or 

strings /bin/busybox | grep 'BusyBox'
```

this one also works, it works by looking for a " v" that has a "." after it without a space character between the "v" and the "."

```
strings /bin/busybox | grep '[ ][v][^ ]*[.]'
```

I see output that looks like

```
syslogd started: BusyBox v1.32.0
BusyBox v1.32.0 (2020-11-03 15:21:44 +03)
```